# Will the number of contrasts in orthogonal contrasts always be number of levels of the factors minus 1?

Tags: r, regression, contrasts

(I'm working in R)
If I want to run a linear model on a dependent variable as a function of a categorical variable with 3 levels (l=3), and I want to use orthogonal contrasts, will I always have to establish l-1 contrasts?

Suppose I want to compare level 1 to level 2, and level 1 to level 3. Assuming the levels are called "1", "2", and "3", I would use contrasts:

```
c(-0.5,0.5,0),  c(-0.5,0,0.5)
```

That is l-1 contrasts. But what if I also want to compare level 2 to level 3? Would I have to build another linear model only for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have an intercept in the model, if you use more than l-1 contrsts your model matrix will be singular. So you cannot do that.

But, after fitting the model you can test the contrasts you want, you will find that a contrast comparing levels 2 and 3 is a linear combination of the two contrasts you have given. There are many similar posts on this site, so look at for instance [Categorical variable coding to compare all levels to all levels](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141255/categorical-variable-coding-to-compare-all-levels-to-all-levels/269746#269746)