# Formulate equation after fitting to log(y)~x) using lm()

Tags: r, regression, fitting, lm

Following code was used to fit a function to my data;

```
# dataset
x <- c(0,10000,20000,30000,40000,50000,60000,70000,80000,90000,100000,110000,120000,130000,140000,150000)
y <- c(1034,908,794,693,602,523,452,392,339,294,255,221,195,171,152,135)

# visualize dataset
plot(x,y, xlim=c(0,160000), ylim=c(0,1200), pch=".")
lines(x, y,lwd=2, col="green")

# fit model
model <- lm(log(y)~x)
prediction <- exp(predict(model,list(Time=y)))

# visualize model
par(new=T)
plot(x,prediction, xlim=c(0,160000), ylim=c(0,1200), pch=".",xlab="", ylab="")
lines(x, prediction,lwd=2, col = "red", xlab = "Time (s)", ylab = "Counts")
```

Values created by `predict()` fit nice to my data;

[image: plot]

Following output is created by `summary(model)`;

```
Call:
lm(formula = log(y) ~ x)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.024165 -0.011078 -0.002164  0.009068  0.036583 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  6.945e+00  7.542e-03   920.9   <2e-16 ***
x           -1.384e-05  8.567e-08  -161.6   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.0158 on 14 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9995,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9994 
F-statistic: 2.61e+04 on 1 and 14 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

As far I'm aware I'm fitting the following model; right?

$\log(y)=X\beta+\epsilon$;

I'm not able to formulate the equation based on above output...
Unfortunately the following (closely related) question did not help me.
[How to translate the results from lm() to an equation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63600/how-to-translate-the-results-from-lm-to-an-equation)

How to formulate the equation? Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Could you be more specific about your problem?  The thread you link to appears to address all the issues you mention.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Somehow I completely missed the obvious solution.... Added answer in case anyone might be as foolish
as me `;)`

Answer (score 0):

How could I've missed the following...  I'm sorry!

```
x <- c(0,10000,20000,30000,40000,50000,60000,70000,80000,90000,100000,110000,120000,130000,140000,150000)
y <- exp(6.945+x*-1.384e-05)
```

Output;

```
[1]   1037.9470  903.7927  786.9778  685.2611  596.6914  519.5692  452.4150  393.9405  343.0239
[10]  298.6881   260.0828  226.4672  197.1964  171.7088  149.5155  130.1907
```